# SPSS - covariance structure and intra-class correlation

Tags: mixed-model, spss, fixed-effects-model, covariance-matrix

I am fitting linear mixed models in SPSS with 2 categorical fixed factors (bolus type and muscle type) and the participants as random factors. Each participant underwent bolus and muscle conditions. My problem is that i don't quite understand how intra-class correlation (ICC) are computed.

So first of all, only the following gives me an actual estimation of the ICC. Which i can also estimate my self with the residuals and intercept variances: ICC = var(intercept) / (var(intercept) + var(residual)).

```
  MIXED meanValues BY bolus muscle
  /CRITERIA=DFMETHOD(SATTERTHWAITE) CIN(95) MXITER(100) MXSTEP(10) SCORING(1) 
    SINGULAR(0.000000000001) HCONVERGE(0.00000001, RELATIVE) LCONVERGE(0, ABSOLUTE) PCONVERGE(0, 
    ABSOLUTE)
  /FIXED=bolus muscle bolus*muscle | SSTYPE(3)
  /METHOD=REML
  /PRINT=SOLUTION TESTCOV
  /RANDOM=INTERCEPT | SUBJECT(id) COVTYPE(VC).
```

[image]

---

Then, if i add repeated variables with scaled identity covariance structure, i don't have the ICC estimation anymore. But i can still estimate it myself. So, **why i don't have ICC estimation here and is there any covariance structure used when no repeat variable is added ?**

```
/REPEATED=bolus*muscle | SUBJECT(id) COVTYPE(ID).
```

[image]

---

Then, if i use more complexe covariance structure, i am quite lost at how i can estimate the ICC myself. With compound symetry, it is still feasible. But the intercept variance changes. So, **does the intercept variance estimate changes essentially because the model better fits the data ?**

[image]

---

Finally, with covariance structure like heteregeneous compoung symetry, **how ICC can be estimated ?**

[image]